# angularjs specific page without ng-incude

Tags: angularjs

I design my pages with angularjs like following

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
  <ng-include="'footer-tpl.html'">
 </body>
</html>
```

so whenever navigate to any pages will just change the ng-view, but now I want to have a 
page without the <`ng-include="'footer-tpl.html'"`>. How to do that?

Comment: (a) Move <ng-include> to every one of your views, removing it from your template, or (b) hide the footer in the controller of the 1 page you want to hide it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized you can use [ngHide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide) with [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude):

http://plnkr.co/edit/BBpfQBRgtr7tAK6iFRTR?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<div ng-include="'footer.html'" ng-hide="hideFooter"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('test', []).controller('test', function ($scope) {
    // TODO set this to true to hide the footer, if you don't set it, it stays visible
    //$scope.hideFooter = true;
});
```

When [this patch for ngIf](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2312) makes it into a release, you can use it in place of ngHide.  It seems like it'll prevent footer.html from even being loaded if you hit the right view, but I'm not totally sure on that.

Comment: Nice,  hopefully ng-if come to real and thanks for your plunker. will use it for temporary